# How do I get this HTML to display formatted, without tags?

Tags: html, asp.net, ckeditor, label, rich-text-editor

I created a blog (for coding practice). I use a Rich Text Editor (ckeditor) and save the post to a database. When I pull the post out to display in a Label.Text, it shows all the HTML tags:

```
<p><strong>there was</strong> once a fox that lived</p>
<p> in the<span style="color: #ff0000"> woods</span></p>
```

How do I get the post to display, with the proper formatting (paragraph, color, etc.), but without the HTML tags?

Comment: Please verify that your output is not filled with `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: Justin808: Hi, the page shows/displays the HTML tags literally per my original post. But when I look at the source code, all the <> are replaced with &gt and &lt. How do I get the browser to read the HTML tags instead of using &gt and ignoring the tags?

Comment: nanonerd: See the answer from ChrisF below. You need to use a `asp:Literal`, not a `asp:Label`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FYI: The literal produced the same result as the Label ... but I got my answer, this works:

```
string strHTML = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
Label.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(strHTML);
```

Answer (score 8):

Well the HTML **is** the formatting, so to get the text to display how you want you need to insert the text *as HTML* into your page rather than inserting the text into the Label.Text - which will treat is as plain text and display all the markup.

So rather than create a Label use a Literal:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="EditorOutput">
```

Then in your page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditorOutput.Text = theText;
}
```

`theText` will be the string:

```
<p><strong>there was</strong> once a fox that lived</p> <p> in the<span style="color: #ff0000"> woods</span></p>
```

as read from your database.

If your string has been [Encoded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) you will have to call [`Server.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) on it to make sure that any `&lt;` and `&gt;` codes are converted back to `<` and `>`.

[Source](http://www.dotnetperls.com/aspliteral)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand.
Do you mean, when you check the post, you get something like:

```
<b>there was</b> once a fox that lived...
```

It's probably a good idea to save it in .html format, since RTFs were never meant for the internet. 
It also sounds like you don't need to use a database in the first place. XML is better for that kind of task.

Comment: He's not using the rich text format, he's using a "rich" text editor (i.e. a WYSIWYG editor) to produce HTML markup.  As for not using a database in favor of XML files: WHAT?